# Change format of DateTime variable in C#, Not string output

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, stored-procedures, datetime-format

How can I convert the format of a C# DateTime variable from `d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss` to `yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss`
I do not want to change a string output, but the DateTime variable itself.

I have a stored procedure with parameter `@date` in datetime.
Now I am trying to pass a DateTime variable `Today` from C# to this stored procedure.
The C# DateTime variable is in format `d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss` but the stored procedure needs the format `yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss`.

I try to this with LINQ to SQL:
code:

```
public static object SP_SelectSalesPriceItem()
{
    var query = dc.SP_SalesPrice(DateTime.Now);
    return query;
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SalesPrice]
    @Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    select SalesPrice.[Item No_]
    from Sales Price 
    where [Starting Date] < @Date and ([Ending Date] > @Date
```

This is the Error I get in asp.net:
**Specified cast is not valid.**

> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +5002837
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i) +38
>   Read_SP_SalesPriceResult(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +1477
>
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +32
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateItemsWithoutGroups(ListViewPagedDataSource
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding, InsertItemPosition insertPosition,
>   ArrayList keyArray) +222
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +1040
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data) +44
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data) +128
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +113
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +55
>   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2496

Comment: A `DateTime` has no format. If you want to pass `Today` anyway, you can also do this in the database directly: `dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)`.

Comment: dateObject.toString("yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss");

Comment: What is dc in this code?  Also, in the [Sales Price] table, what is the data type of the [Starting Date] and [Ending Date] columns?

Comment: Just realised you've not yet told us what the error is! What exception are you actually getting?

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is not possible for the simple reason that a `DateTime` **does not have a format**.

A format is the **string** representation of a `DateTime`.

The stored procedure should be taking a `DATETIME` parameter for `@date` - if it isn't, you are doing something wrong.

If you are using a `NVARCHAR` or such type you will need to call `ToString` on your `DateTime` in C# with the correct format before adding the parameter value.

Comment: the stored procedure is taking a datetime, but when I pass DateTime.now I get the folowing error: Specified cast is not valid. Also when I enter 14-11-2012 as value on Execute Stored Procedure on the sql server itself, I get the error: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime. This does not happen when I give 2012-11-14 as value

Comment: @bart_dp - Where are you casting? How have you defined the parameter in C#? How is it used in the SP?

Comment: @bart_dp - please post the entire error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: Error and stack trace added.

Comment: Solution found, table in stored procedure was not named

Answer (score 2):

You can't - the internals of how `DateTime` are stored aren't something that can be changed.  All it really is is the number of "ticks" since a given date.

> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks that would be added by leap seconds). For example, a ticks value of 31241376000000000L represents the date, Friday, January 01, 0100 12:00:00 midnight.

If you must pass it as a string, rather than a `datetime`, you should just convert it `ToString("yyyy/M/d HH:mm:ss")` and pass that to your parameter.  That's almost certainly what's happening internally anyway now, based on what you said in your question, only with the default `ToString()` formatting.

Comment: No, the parameter should also be a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @Oded - True, but if that was the case the OP shouldn't be having this problem.  Admittedly, that *is* a better answer than treating it as a string, provide it's possible to make that change.

Comment: Highly recommend not following the advice ("convert it") - @Oded is quite right, the parameter should be `datetime` or similar, not a string. The stored procedure should be changed if it currently takes a string.

Comment: @tomfanning - Edited to clarify that.  The stored procedure might not be able to changed, and/or it might be being stored in the database as a string.  I've heard of worse.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, a `DateTime` has no "format", neither in .NET or in T-SQL. `DateTime` is a .NET type which strongly represents a date and time.

Whatever you are doing, make sure the stored procedure parameter for the date is the T-SQL type `datetime` (or one of its friends), and not `varchar` or similar.

Comment: the parameter in the stored procedure is a datetime. When I pass DateTime.now in C# I get the folowing error: Specified cast is not valid. Also when I enter 14-11-2012 as value on Execute Stored Procedure on the sql server itself, I get the error: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime. This does not happen when I give 2012-11-14 as value

Comment: Those two facts are not related. We can help you get this right. Please update the question with some code showing (1) how you are calling the stored procedure from C#, and (2) enough of the stored procedure to show its parameters.

Comment: @bart_dp - Also show the complete error message.  There should be more to it besides just 'Specified cast is not valid'.  It should tell you what cast is not valid.

Comment: The stored procedure is correct enough - but the C# you've shown us is barely relevant. Drill down through your business/data layer to where the query is actually executed (probably against an `SqlConnection` object)

Comment: @tomfanning - He's using Linq-to-SQL.  That code snippet is all that it exposes to the user - the rest is in the codebehind for the DBML and outside user control. I suspect it's actually the types of the columns he's comparing to.

Comment: What data type is the field `SalesPrice.[Item No_]` in your database?

Comment: Solution found, table in stored procedure was not named, thanks anyway!